# Induced p-norm of a Random matrix

Tags: matrices, random-matrices

This question is related to my earlier question 
[here](http://tiny.cc/ga9k1) .

Given an $n\times n$ random matrix $A$, is determining the properties (mean, variance,moments,etc.) of its induced $p$-norm ($p\neq 0,1,2,\infty$) a good research problem?

Looking at related work, I couldn't find anything much except a paper by Hansen on the 2-norm  [here](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=49940) . Also Terence Tao's page  [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/15/random-matrices-universality-of-local-eigenvalue-statistics-up-to-the-edge/)  on random matrices talks about singular values of a random matrix ; I don't know if there is a trivial extension from these results to determining its $p$ -norm.

I don't have a pure maths background and would much appreciate suggestions.

Comment: The question seems interesting, but I don't know if it is worthwhile, because no immediate application springs to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some papers you might want to look at if you're interested in this issue (probably better than the paper of mine that Suvrit mentioned):

1. [G. Bennett, V. Goodman, and C.M. Newman. Norms of random matrices.
   Pacific J. Math. 59 (1975), no. 2, 359–365.](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102905342)
2. Grahame Bennett. Lectures on matrix transformations of $l_p$ spaces. Notes in Banach spaces, pp. 39--80, Univ. Texas Press, Austin, Tex., 1980. (specifically, section 4 of this paper)
3. Stanisław Szarek. Condition numbers of random matrices. J. Complexity 7 (1991), no. 2, 131–149.
4. [Kenneth R. Davidson and Stanislaw J. Szarek. Local operator theory, random matrices and Banach spaces. Handbook of the geometry of Banach spaces, Vol. I, 317–366, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2001.](http://www.cwru.edu/artsci/math/szarek/TeX/DavSzaHB.pdf) (specifically, the end of section 2.3 of this paper)

The third of these deals explicitly with the question of deducing results about the induced $p$-norm from results about singular values.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a paper by Mark Meckes (I hope he sees your post and gives a more informed answer than mine), that seems to go a long way towards answering your question.

In the following paper: Concentration of norms and eigenvalues of random matrices. J. Funct. Anal. 211 (2004) no. 2, 508-524. (Links: [Paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-1236%2803%2900198-8) or [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211192)), the author proves concentration (around a median) results for $\ell_p$ operator norms of random matrices. The techniques of that paper should help you further.